# Selenium NoSuchMethodError

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, automated-tests

I am writing an automated test framework and have already written a substantial amount. However, I have come across an error which I cannot seem to fix or find a solution for.

The problem occurs when selenium tries to answer a date question and select from a dropdown menu of dates. I have achieved this loads of times with no problems, but for some reason I get the error as displayed in the title. After trying to find a solution on google I decided to come here as there seems to be nothing out there that's similar.

The code where my automated test breaks is:

```
new Select(driver.findElement(By.id("AMOUNT_OF_DHP_DATE_FROM_d"))).selectByVisibleText("4th");

new Select(driver.findElement(By.id("AMOUNT_OF_DHP_DATE_FROM_m"))).selectByIndex(4);
    driver.findElement(By.id("AMOUNT_OF_DHP_DATE_FROM_y")).sendKeys("2017");
    driver.findElement(By.id("AMOUNT_OF_DHP_WEEKLY")).sendKeys("50");

new  Select(driver.findElement(By.id("AMOUNT_OF_DHP_DATE_TO_d"))).getFirstSelectedOption();

new Select(driver.findElement(By.id("AMOUNT_OF_DHP_DATE_TO_m"))).getFirstSelectedOption();

driver.findElement(By.id("AMOUNT_OF_DHP_DATE_TO_y")).sendKeys("2017");
clickNext();
```

The error occurs on the lines where the methods `selectByVisibleText` and `selectByIndex` is used. I have used these methods hundreds of times before with no issues.. When I run the tests in the browser with the Selenium IDE it executes with no problems. But as soon as the code is transferred across to Eclipse it doesnt work.

The only thing I can possibly think of is that I have converted the project from JUnit to TestNG.. Would this have any implications? I have done this before though without any issues.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

### EDIT

Stacktrace:

> java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.openqa.selenium.WebElement.setSelected()V
>
> at org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.Select.selectByVisibleText(Select.java:111)
>
> at   tns_automation.DHP_Forms.DhpAbstractTest.answerAmountOfDHPQuestion(DhpAbstractTest.java:348)
>
> at tns_automation.DHP.KnowsleyDHPTest.completeAssessmentFormAndBudgetToolBeforeDownloadingPDFFromInTrayWithCookiesEnabled(KnowsleyDHPTest.java:62)
>
> at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
>
> at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
>
> at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
>
> at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
>
> at org.testng.internal.MethodInvocationHelper.invokeMethod(MethodInvocationHelper.java:108)
>
> at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeMethod(Invoker.java:661)
>
> at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeTestMethod(Invoker.java:869)
>
> at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeTestMethods(Invoker.java:1193)
>
> at org.testng.internal.TestMethodWorker.invokeTestMethods(TestMethodWorker.java:126)
>
> at org.testng.internal.TestMethodWorker.run(TestMethodWorker.java:109)
>
> at org.testng.TestRunner.privateRun(TestRunner.java:744)
>
> at org.testng.TestRunner.run(TestRunner.java:602)
>
> at org.testng.SuiteRunner.runTest(SuiteRunner.java:380)
>
> at org.testng.SuiteRunner.runSequentially(SuiteRunner.java:375)
>
> at org.testng.SuiteRunner.privateRun(SuiteRunner.java:340)
>
> at org.testng.SuiteRunner.run(SuiteRunner.java:289)
>
> at org.testng.SuiteRunnerWorker.runSuite(SuiteRunnerWorker.java:52)
>
> at org.testng.SuiteRunnerWorker.run(SuiteRunnerWorker.java:86)
>
> at org.testng.TestNG.runSuitesSequentially(TestNG.java:1301)
>
> at org.testng.TestNG.runSuitesLocally(TestNG.java:1226)
>
> at org.testng.TestNG.runSuites(TestNG.java:1144)
>
> at org.testng.TestNG.run(TestNG.java:1115)
>
> at org.testng.remote.AbstractRemoteTestNG.run(AbstractRemoteTestNG.java:126)
>
> at org.testng.remote.RemoteTestNG.initAndRun(RemoteTestNG.java:152)
>
> at org.testng.remote.RemoteTestNG.main(RemoteTestNG.java:57)

Comment: provide full stack of exception..to under stand better

Comment: stacktrace above

Comment: check here DhpAbstractTest.java:348  there may some type and also check import is correct org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.Select

Comment: The code above is taken directly from DhpAbstractTest and the code is called in my TestClass. The import is also correct.

Comment: I have resolved this issue. I simply imported the latest selenium dependency in to my pom.xml. Still a strange issue but it is now fixed. Thanks for the help :)

Answer (score 2):

This issue has been resolved by importing the latest selenium maven dependency in to my pom.xml. I still can't understand why this issue occurred as I have used it in other projects. The maven dependency to fix the issue:

```
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.seleniumhq.selenium/selenium-java -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
        <artifactId>selenium-java</artifactId>
        <version>3.3.1</version>
    </dependency>
```

Answer (score 0):

I had same problem then I try to add dependency like `user3008643`'s answer, but it still no working.

`user3008643` said it works for him, so I looked my `pom.xml` carefully, then I found out something weird:

**I had imported 3 version of selenium dependencies.**

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
    <artifactId>selenium-chrome-driver</artifactId>
    <version>3.11.0</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
    <artifactId>selenium-support</artifactId>
    <version>2.0a7</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
    <artifactId>selenium-java</artifactId>
    <version>3.12.0</version>
</dependency>
```

It's really nonsense, so I changed it to same version `3.12`.

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
    <artifactId>selenium-chrome-driver</artifactId>
    <version>3.12.0</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
    <artifactId>selenium-support</artifactId>
    <version>3.12.0</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
    <artifactId>selenium-java</artifactId>
    <version>3.12.0</version>
</dependency>
```

After updated dependencies, the problem had been fixed.

I think the problem is about dependencies, **you have to import the same version of dependencies.**

Answer (score 0):

In my case constructor were causing this problem i removed it but later found out that i didn't make constructor public. Probably making constructor public would help. Selenium Java*