# Getting "Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.openqa.selenium.WebElement.setSelected()V" error

Tags: java, maven, selenium, drop-down-menu

I'm trying to select a value in drop down but getting the `Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.openqa.selenium.WebElement.setSelected()` error in maven project.

Code:

```
Select dropdown = new Select(driver.findElement(By.xpath("//select[@name=\"ppw-expirationDate_year\"]")));
dropdown.selectByVisibleText("2025");
```

Error:

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.openqa.selenium.WebElement.setSelected()V
>       at org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.Select.selectByVisibleText(Select.java:111)
>       at Test.Test1.AppTest.main(AppTest.java:62)

Comment: refer this solution [Selenium NoSuchMethodError](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42997732/selenium-nosuchmethoderror)

Comment: Thank you ..It worked after adding the dependencies mentioned in the link.

Answer (score 0):

Try with below code :

```
Select dropdown = new Select(driver.findElement(By.xpath("//select[@name='ppw-expirationDate_year']")));
dropdown.selectByVisibleText("2025");
```

You have to make sure that you are writing attribute values in single quotes and removing the escape character which IDE puts by default.